# Why is there such error of "arm-linux-gcc: not found"?

Tags: gnu-make

For building u-boot of my board, I followed below two commands as told:

```
$ sudo make nanopi_h3_defconfig ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-
$ sudo make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-
```

I got the result from the 1st command: **configuration written to .config**
It means success. But got the below from the 2nd command:

```
make: arm-linux-gcc: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: 1: arm-linux-gcc: not found
dirname: missing operand
Try 'dirname --help' for more information.
scripts/kconfig/conf  --silentoldconfig Kconfig
./scripts/binutils-version.sh: line 18: arm-linux-as: command not found
  CHK     include/config.h
  CFG     u-boot.cfg
/bin/sh: 1: arm-linux-gcc: not found
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.autoconf:79: u-boot.cfg] Error 1
make: *** No rule to make target 'include/config/auto.conf', needed by 'include/config/uboot.release'.  Stop.
```

It seems trouble coming from arm-linux-gcc, but I ran command 'arm-linux-gcc', it works. So, why can the first command pass through arm-linux-gcc, but the 2nd command failed?

Comment: Is sudo(8) absolutely necessary? Usually programs in Unix-like systems are compiled without root privileges, it is the _installation_ which needs them. Does the "advice" mention setting up path or the environment in any way?

Comment: The 1st command: " make sunxi_defconfig ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-" failed due to 'permission' and it works if I added 'sudo' to it.

The 2nd command failed no matter adding 'sudo' or not, but with different ways of failure:

I added 'sudo' to the commands by myself and the original commands from the web don't have 'sudo'

Comment: The error message of the 2nd one without 'sudo' is
/bin/sh: 1: cannot create scripts/basic/modules.order: Permission denied
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:496: scripts/basic/modules.order] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:463: scripts_basic] Error 2
make: *** No rule to make target 'include/config/auto.conf', needed by 'include/config/kernel.release'.  Stop.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the most important parts of the output relevant to the question.

Comment: The most important parts of output were already on the original post, on the quoted portion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I’m guessing the problem is that your ARM toolchain is installed somewhere that’s not on `root`’s `PATH`; since you’re building with `sudo`, the compiler can’t be found.

To fix that, restore the correct ownership on all the files in the build tree:

```
sudo chown -R $USER .
```

(`sudo` is required here since you don’t own all the files.)

Now run the build *without* `sudo`:

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-
```

The only part of the kernel build where you need to run it as `root` is the installation phases; since you’re cross-compiling you won’t ever need to do that on the build system (you’ll presumably be copying the built kernel and modules to another device, and installing them there).

Comment: Great, I followed your instructions and it went thru very far. Although it still failed with the below error, I believe it has nothing to do with the problem we're discussing.
/usr/bin/env: ‘python2’: No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:1150: u-boot-sunxi-with-spl.bin] Error 127

Comment: So, it's obvious that I committed an error due to adding 'sudo' before the given commands.